# What is the difference between cursor and view?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

What is the difference between `cursor` and `view` ?
Because none of them store data in the database.

Comment: That's about the only thing that isn't different.. They are completely different concepts. They aren't related except that they are both to do with databases.

Comment: What is more amazing is that being completely different by meaning these terms don't even share a single common letter!

Comment: @Azar: "view is customized table" --- this is indeed wrong. View can hold a query that doesn't interact with any tables.

Comment: I am sorry serkms  I havent seen the tag , in sql server it means the same

Comment: @Azar no, it doesn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A cursor is defined and used within the scope of a stored procedure (it is used with PL/SQL).

On the other hand, a view is a database object (similar to a table), which can be used even outside of stored procedures as well, as in queries (it can be used with both SQL and PL/SQL).

**Reference**:

1. [Views on Oracle Database Concepts](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/schema.htm#i20690)
2. [Cursors on Oracle Magazine](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2013/13-mar/o23plsql-1906474.html)

Answer (score 1):

A view is a pre-defined query which is stored in the database and can be used much like a table.

A cursor is a data structure which provides access to the rowset returned by a query.

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

`VIEWS` are for easy usage like `MACROS` except *materialized* Views.

Materialised views have data stored up in memory. Where as other views when queried, simply gets replaced with the coressponding definition while executed. And it is available for everyone to query, until they have privilege to access it.

`CURSORS` other way is a different thing. It is pointing to a resultset of somequery available to the creator of it. Either a `PL/SQL` or any other `OCI` calls.

Answer (score 0):

Cursors are handy to set up report data, since the simplest way to make a
report is to set up a rather non-normalized table of the data in the
appropriate order, and run from there.

Views are used a lot by developers who don't know whether the end user will
have Fox tables or use SQL-server, or whose Fox tables are reaching their
limit and might be migrated for size reasons.  The programming which uses
the views (the grid on the form) is the same whether the view is local or
remote.  Then, when the data is migrated, the effort to change from local
views to remote views is small.